# override paperclip has_attached_file settings that were set in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

In my project i have a gem that uses paperclip for file attachments. an example model in the gem:

```
class Example do
...
    has_attached_file :image,
      styles: { mini: '32x32>', normal: '128x128>' },
      default_style: :mini,
      url: '/example/url/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
      path: ':rails_root/public/example/url/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
...
end
```

I want to modify the image so instead of having `mini` and `normal` sizes, i can add another size. I also want to change the path. How do i go about this? i tried creating a decorator like:

```
Example.class_eval do
    has_attached_file :image,
      styles: { mini: '32x32>', normal: '128x128>', large: '1024x1024' },
      default_style: :mini,
      url: '/example/url/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
      path: 'updated/example/url/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
end
```

this didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you've solved this by now, but for any future viewers of this question...

You can do this by modifying the `attachment_definitions` property of the class. For instance you could add an initializer with:

```
Example.attachment_definitions[:image][:styles][:normal] = "1000x500"
Example.attachment_definitions[:image][:path] = '...'
```